Evaluating $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-tx}\sin{t}}{t}dt, x>0$
The task is to compute
$$F(x) = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-tx}\sin{t}}{t}dt, x>0 $$
and from simple integration by parts one can see that
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-xt}\sin{t}dt = \frac{1}{1+x^2}. $$
What I tried to do was differentiate F(x) with respect to x (under the integral sign) which gave
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-xt}\sin{t}}{t}dt = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{-te^{-xt}\sin{t}}{t}dt = -\frac{1}{1+x^2}  $$
I think that the answer is then found by integrating with respect to x on both sides ($x\in(0,\infty)$):
$$F(x)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-xt}\sin{t}}{t}dt = -\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=[-arctan(x)]_0^{\infty} = -\frac{\pi}{2}+ 0 = -\frac{\pi}{2}  $$
But the answer sheet says that the answer is $ F(x) = -arctan(x) + \frac{\pi}{2}$. Where did I go wrong?

@DaveL.Renfro My thought process was that $\int\frac{d}{dx}F(x)dx = F(x) = \int (-\frac{1}{1+x^2})dx$, I'm not sure how else to do it.

Does this answer your question? Laplace transform of sinc function

Please consider accepting the answer, such that the topic can be closed. Otherwise, if there are still some questions, feel free to reach out.

Your very last line of equations is wrong. Especially the second equation in this line is not true. The fundamental theorem of calculus tells you, that
$$F(b)-F(a)=\int_a^b \frac{dF}{dx}(s)ds$$
If anything, you would need to write
$$F(\infty)-F(0)=-\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+s^2}ds,$$
which is not equal to $F(x)$. Your mistake is, that you have picked boundary values. You should have written
$$
\begin{aligned}
F(x)
&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-xt}\sin{t}}{t}dt =\int \frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-xt}\sin{t}}{t}dt\bigg)dx\\
&= -\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=-\arctan(x) + C
\end{aligned}$$
You can find the constant by using the boundaries $b=x$ and $a=0$ in the fundamental theorem of calculus. You find
$$F(x)-F(0)=\int_0^x \frac{dF}{dx}(s) ds=-\int_0^x\frac{1}{1+s^2}ds=-\arctan(s)\big|_{s=0}^{s=x}=-\arctan(x)$$
With $F(0)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin t}{t}dt = \frac{\pi}{2}$, you find
$$F(x)=-\arctan(x)+F(0)=-\arctan(x)+\frac{\pi}{2}$$

I think in the fundamental theorem of calculus it should be $\int_a^b \frac{d}{dx}F(x)dx $ and not $\int_a^b \frac{d}{dx}F(s)ds $.

Yes, it is commonly written like this, but it does not make a difference. You can also just write $\int_a^b F'(s)ds$, if you want. I only changed the name of the integration variable to prevent confusion with the boundary point $x$ and the integration variable in the equation $F(x)-F(0)=\ldots$
